# Why is the amount of force/moment transfer occurring between bodies in FEA is independent of mesh size?

Tags: finite-element-method, numerical-methods

So I read somewhere that the mesh size won't effect the amount of force transfer occurring between bodies if several bodies are in contact, and a global force is applied somewhere. I wanted to know why is this the case?

Comment: What do you understand about mesh size and what it does?

Comment: Why do you think the real-world object "knows" how to change its behavior depending on the mesh size of your model? It should be obvious that *correct* output from the model doesn't depend on the mesh size.

Comment: @SolarMike, so bascially we vary the mesh size if we want to observe a difference in the results after solution. A finer mesh size would give a relatively accurate results for displacements, stresses and strains. But it won't change the amount of force transfer, thats what I have heard. So why would only the displacements/stresses/strains would have a difference in the values but not the force going through the elements, is my basic concern.

Comment: @alephzero, I mean why would the displacements, stresses, strains would be more accurate now. Doesn't it have to do anything with the force passing through the elements before and after mesh refinement?

Answer (score 1):

Forces do not disappear without resistance. For a statically balanced system, globally, the sum of the applied Forces **must equal to** the sum of the resistance forces, so the number, and size of the mesh will not affect the result.

However, the number and size of the mesh will affect the pattern of the internal forces/stresses. Usually, it is advisable to provide finer mesh near the concentrated forces, sharp corners, and openings where distorted results may occur due to stress concentrations.